# Where do I create/instantiate repositories in DDD that are used my Domain Services

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

From what I understand a DomainService should be implemented against a RepositoryInterface, so we could change with easy the repository (which its a part of the Infrastructure layer)

So, if I have:

```
class UserService{

    function __construct(UserRepository $rep){
        $this->rep = $rep;
    }

    function createNewUser($attributes){
        return $this->rep->create($attributes)->persist();
    }
}
```

It means, that in my ApplicationService (some call it Action) i would have:

```

```
class UserAplicationService{

    function create(UserCreateCommand $command){
        $service = new UserService(new UserRepoitory());
        $service->create($command->getAttributes())
    }
}
```

```

That means that every time  I use my DomainService I have to instantiate my repository object. Doen't make this ApplicationServices to be coupled with Repository Implmentation?

**Question**: Where should I instantiate repository objects that are used in Domain Services?

Answer (score 1):

Miško Hevery writes often about Dependency Injection.  [video](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/11/clean-code-talks-dependency-injection/)

The usual answer is that you are going to instantiate your repository object when you connection your application to your persistence layer: ie, when you are assembling your object graph (in other words, during your initialization procedure, before you start processing requests).

```
UserRepository $repository = $frobozzMagicUserRepositoryFactory.create(...)
UserService $userService = new UserService($repository)
UserApplicationService $userApplicationService = new UserApplicationService($userService)
```

Comment: So your Controller (or wherever you call your ApplicationService will be called) will be aware of your Repositories?

Comment: @user237329 No, the `UserApplicationService` only knows about `UserService` and uses its API, it has no idea that `UserService` may actually contain a repository.

Comment: I was asking abouy the Controller. I was looking at the example tha @VoiceOfUnreason gave. The last 3 lines

Comment: I was following your question - if you put what you think the Controller looks like in your question, I'll try to match it in my answer.

Comment: Your controllers are often automatically instantiated by frameworks and these frameworks usually support automatic dependency injection mechanisms. You want to register these dependencies with the injector and let the framework do the rest.